# How to convert Array{Array{Float64, 1}, 1} to Matrix in julia?

Tags: julia

Let's say I have input of this kind:

```
> [[0.8681299566762923,-0.3472589826095631], [3.2300860990307445,3.3731249077464946]]
```

How can I convert it to more pleasant type like Matrix (knowing dimensions)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use splatting (`...`) and `hcat` to get what you are after:

```
julia> a = Vector[[0.8681299566762923,-0.3472589826095631], [3.2300860990307445,3.3731249077464946]]
2-element Array{Array{T,1},1}:
 [0.8681299566762923,-0.3472589826095631]
 [3.2300860990307445,3.3731249077464946]

julia> hcat(a...)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.86813   3.23009
 -0.347259  3.37312
```

Or if you wanted stop stack as rows instead of columns you could do the following:

```
julia> vcat(map(x->x', a)...)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.86813  -0.347259
 3.23009   3.37312
```

I don't recommend building a `Matrix` row by row as that is in conflict with Julia's [column major array layout](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns). For larger matrices it is actually more efficient to stack as columns and transpose the output:

```
julia> a2 = Vector{Float64}[rand(10) for i=1:5000];

julia> stackrows1{T}(a::Vector{Vector{T}}) = vcat(map(transpose, a)...)::Matrix{T}
stackrows1 (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> stackrows2{T}(a::Vector{Vector{T}}) = hcat(a...)'::Matrix{T}
stackrows2 (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> stackrows1(a2) == stackrows2(a2)  # run once to compile and make sure functions do the same thing
true

julia> @time for i=1:100 stackrows1(a2); end
elapsed time: 0.142792896 seconds (149 MB allocated, 7.85% gc time in 7 pauses with 0 full sweep)

julia> @time for i=1:100 stackrows2(a2); end
elapsed time: 0.05213114 seconds (88 MB allocated, 12.60% gc time in 4 pauses with 0 full sweep)
```

Comment: This is much better than my approach. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot, I came up with solution with flatten first then use reshape but it is slow and ugly.

Comment: With Julia 1.0 you can get a bit better performance with `reduce(hcat, x)` and `transpose(reduce(hcat, x))` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For a general function that will work in most situations, throw an error if there are problems, and allow you to choose the shape of the output matrix, I'm having a hard time coming up with anything smarter than the following (admittedly inelegant looking) solution:

```
function toMatrix{T<:Any}(x::Vector{Vector{T}}, dim::Int=1)
    if length(x) == 0
        return(Array(T, 0, 0))
    else
        N = length(x[1])
        M = length(x)
        if dim == 1
            xMat = Array(T, N, M)
            for m = 1:M
                if length(x[m]) != N
                    error("Conversion not possible due to vector length mismatch")
                end
                for n = 1:N
                    xMat[n, m] = x[m][n]
                end
            end
        elseif dim == 2
            xMat = Array(T, M, N)
            for m = 1:M
                if length(x[m]) != N
                    error("Conversion not possible due to vector length mismatch")
                end
                for n = 1:N
                    xMat[m, n] = x[m][n]
                end
            end         
        else
            error("Invalid dimension argument")
        end
        return(xMat)
    end
end
```

I'll be interested to see what solutions other users can come up with. I'm certainly not aware of a function in `Base` that does what you're after...