# Converting Array{Array{Float64,1},1} to Array{Float64,2} in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

My problem is similar to the problem described [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164632/how-to-convert-arrayarrayfloat64-1-1-to-matrix-in-julia?rq=1),
 with the difference that I don't input numbers manually. Thus the accepted answer there does not work for me.

I want to convert the vector of cartesian coordinates to polars:

```
function cart2pol(x0,
                  x1)
    rho = sqrt(x0^2 + x1^2)
    phi = atan2(x1, x0)
    return [rho, phi]
end

@vectorize_2arg Number cart2pol

function cart2pol(x)
    x1 = view(x,:,1)
    x2 = view(x,:,2)
    return cart2pol(x1, x2)
end



x = rand(5,2)

vcat(cart2pol(x))
```

The last command does not collect Arrays for some reason, returning the output of type `5-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`. Any idea how to cast it to `Array{Float64,2}`?

Comment: The answer in the question you linked should work just fine.  You just need to [_splat_](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/faq/#splits-one-argument-into-many-different-arguments-in-function-calls) the array of arrays: `hcat(cart2pol(x)...)` or `vcat(map(transpose, cart2pol(x))...)`.  Those three dots are significant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `cat` (which is the underlying function for `hcat` and `vcat`), you see that you can collect several arrays into one single array of dimension 2:

```
cat(2, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6])

2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  5
 2  4  6
```

This is basically what you want. The problem is that you have all your output polar points in an array itself. `cat` expects you to provide them as several arguments. This is where `...` comes in.

> `...` used to cause a single function argument to be split apart into many different arguments when used in the context of a function call.

Therefore, you can write

```
cat(2, [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]...)

2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  5
 2  4  6
```

In your situation, it works exactly in the same way (I changed your `x` to have the points in columns):

```
x=rand(2,5)
cat(2, cart2pol.(view(x,1,:),view(x,2,:))...)

2×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.587301  0.622    0.928159  0.579749  0.227605
 1.30672   1.52956  0.352177  0.710973  0.909746
```

Comment: We should really have a function to do this without splatting; accordingly, I've opened an issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21672.

Answer (score 4):

The function `mapslices` can also do this, essentially transforming the rows of the input:

```
julia> x = rand(5,2)
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.458583   0.205246 
 0.285189   0.992547 
 0.947025   0.0853141
 0.79599    0.67265  
 0.0273176  0.381066 

julia> mapslices(row->cart2pol(row[1],row[2]), x, [2])
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.502419  0.420827 
 1.03271   1.291    
 0.95086   0.0898439
 1.04214   0.701612 
 0.382044  1.49923
```

The last argument specifies dimensions to operate over; e.g. passing `[1]` would transform columns.

As an aside, I would encourage one or two stylistic changes. First, it's good to map like to like, so if we stick with the row representation then `cart2pol` should accept a 2-element array (since that's what it returns). Then this call would just be `mapslices(cart2pol, x, [2])`. Or, if what we're really trying to represent is an array of coordinates, then the data could be an array of tuples `[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ...]`, and `cart2pol` could accept and return a tuple. In either case `cart2pol` would not need to be able to operate on arrays, and it's partly for this reason that we've deprecated the `@vectorize_` macros.

Comment: +1 I considered myself to include the  *make `cart2pol` consistent* (or "map like to like" as you say) in my answer. It just doesn't look nice when you have a function converting from one coordinate system to another and it takes a tuple and outputs an array.

Comment: Agreed, I would make both tuples, or both arrays. I think in the future we will also improve the situation by allowing tuple destructuring in formal arguments, i.e. `function cart2pol((x0,x1)) ... return (rho,phi) end` so the argument and return look more similar.